# Bootstrap not overriding CSS properly

Tags: html, css

I was looking for a strange problem I am facing. 
I am using bootstrap 4 for a theme for wordpress and I have to put CSS call twice for it make a change. If I change it back to 1 call of class it doesn't work. Does anyone know the problem?

Here is my code:

```
<title>Theme</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.css'; ?>">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.js'; ?>">
</script>


<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light px-5 mt-0">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
                <span class="w-100 d-lg-none d-block"><!-- hidden spacer to center brand on mobile --></span>

  <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-lg-inline-block" href="#">
    <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo("template_directory"); ?>/assets/logo.png" width="173" height="40" alt="Joint Academy" />
  </a>
</nav>
 <div class="w-auto text-right">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-1 text-right " id="myNavbar" >
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto flex-nowrap  ">
      <li class="nav-item active px-3 ">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">link1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">link2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item px-3">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">link3</a>
      </li>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-outline-dark px-4 py-1">Log In</button>


    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

AND CSS...

```
.jumbotron {
    width: 400px;
}
.jumbotron {
    width: 400px;
}
```

If I delete one jumbotron it doesn't work

Comment: is this CSS how it appears in the CSS file? Or have you just put them next to each other to simplify things for this example?

Comment: I accidentally put them twice and it worked, but If I delete one of them in the CSS file the overriding doesn't work :/

Comment: I understand, but where in the CSS file are they? are they next to each other or on different lines in the file? Is there CSS code in between them?

Comment: Most likely, just before your first `.jumbotron {}` you have a *typo*, which makes it get parsed as something else than `.jumbotron`. Hence, it does not apply. But its ending `}` closes that faulty declaration and the next one applies correctly. Bottom line: if you can't reproduce it here, we can't tell you the cause with certainty.

Comment: No, they are next to each other but I have tried changing lines aswell, and its the same

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu this looks likely

Comment: Well, what you are describing does not make sense. If the first declaration is not affected by previous code, and doesn't apply because the selector is too weak, the second one should not apply, either. Because the second one applies the only possible cause is that the first one is affected by previous code and `.jumbotron` is something else (i.e: `; .jumbotron`, which is not a valid selector). But the simplest way to fix this is: copy/paste enough of your code to reproduce the problem here and we'll tell you exactly what's going on.

Comment: Try validating your CSS code to check if there are any errors: http://csslint.net

Comment: It's getting me only one error, that I use the same twice lol. I will try to run a full cache cleaning on browser and my comp, will see if it solves anything. Thanks for your helps guys!

Comment: My guess is that you miss a semicolon or parathesis in your css code, pls check carefully

Answer (score -1):

use the `!important` tag to override properties

```
.jumbotron {
    width: 400px !important;
}
```

Comment: This should work but should only be used as a last resort because it can't be overridden again.

Comment: Where are your custom styles loaded? before or after bootstrap.css?

Comment: It looks like they are after, enqueued by `wp_head()`

Comment: are you cleaning your browser cache? try in incognito mode, I do not see any error

Comment: Yes, i have tried that also. But its very strange, it just won't work and I can't see the problem either.

Comment: `!important` is a good verifier that the problem is not specificity, but the selector itself. Everything so far points to the fact the first `.jumbotron` is not parsed as `.jumbotron`, probably because of an unclosed bracket, a stray comma, dot, semi-colon or other char after the end of the last declaration. The simplest way to check is to look in the source of the loaded stylesheet itself (it can be opened in developer toos).